# JUnit testing complex numbers. Error I don't understand

Tags: java, junit, complex-numbers

I'm getting an error I don't quite understand. My goal is to create a simple program that adds, subtracts, multiplies, and divides complex numbers. My ComplexNumber class compiles correctly, but when I try to compile with the first test case of my Tester class it gives me this error:

> ```
> ComplexNumberTest.java:37: error: method add in class ComplexNumber cannot be applied to given types;
>     assertEquals(test1.add()==0);
>                       ^
>   required: ComplexNumber
>   found: no argument
>   reason: actual and formal arguments differ in length
> ```

This is my add method

```
import java.lang.ArithmeticException;

public class ComplexNumber{
private float a; //real
private float b; //imaginary

public ComplexNumber(float a,float b)
{
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
} //end constructor



public ComplexNumber add(ComplexNumber otherNumber){
    ComplexNumber newComplex;
    float newA = a + otherNumber.getA();
    float newB = b + otherNumber.getB();
    newComplex = new ComplexNumber(newA, newB);
    return newComplex;
}//end add
```

This is my Tester class

```
import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class ComplexNumberTest extends TestCase{

private ComplexNumber test1;
private ComplexNumber test2;
private ComplexNumber test3;
private ComplexNumber test4;
private ComplexNumber test5;


public void setUp(){
    test1 = new ComplexNumber (1,-1);
    test2 = new ComplexNumber(2,2);
    test3 = new ComplexNumber(0,2);
    test4 = new ComplexNumber(3,1);
    test5 = new ComplexNumber(4,4);
}//end set up


/**
 * A method used to test the add method.
 * add two Complex numbers together
 * (ai+bi)=a+bi
 * 
 **/ 
public void testAdd()
{
    assertEquals(test1.add()==0);
    //assertTrue(test2.add()==4);
    //assertEquals(test3.add()==2);
    //assertEquals(test4.add()==3);
    //assertEquals(test5.add()==8);
}//end testAddition
```

I feel like the solution is fairly simple and I've just been staring at it for too long. Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 3):

The error says it all:

```
ComplexNumberTest.java:37: error: method add in class ComplexNumber cannot be applied to given types;
    assertEquals(test1.add()==0);
                      ^
  required: ComplexNumber
  found: no argument
  reason: actual and formal arguments differ in length
```

It is saying that it found no argument when you tried to use `add()`. It also says that it requires a `ComplexNumber` in the argument.

```
public ComplexNumber add(ComplexNumber otherNumber){
    ComplexNumber newComplex;
    float newA = a + otherNumber.getA();
    float newB = b + otherNumber.getB();
    newComplex = new ComplexNumber(newA, newB);
    return newComplex; }//end add
```

You defined `add` to require another `ComplexNumber` to be passed as an argument which you haven't done when you used it as `test1.add()`.

Additionally, based on the method signature of `add`, it will never return 0 as you have assumed in your assertion.

Comment: Okay, I see that now. So if I did something like test1.add(test2)==(3,1), the format would still be wrong though, correct?
In my head, it works like (a1, b1) + (a2,b2) = (a1+a2), (b1+b2). but when I compile this it is expecting additional parentheses.

Comment: @Klate Yes, because your `add` method is returning a `ComplexNumber` object and `(3,1)` is invalid syntax. If you want to compare the return to another `ComplexNumber`, you need to implement the [`equals` and `hashCode` methods](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27581/2557554) for `ComplexNumber`.

Comment: I knew I was missing something. I completely left out the equals to method. Thank you for your help

Comment: @Klate Please accept this answer if it answered your question.